# Remove Disks to confirm they are unused

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

BACKGROUND:

One of my linux servers (running on vmware) had gone through a series of disk replacements, and resizing. Unfortunately I was not involved in these changes. I am now looking at the server and I found 4 disks which are not mounted in the OS. The disks are thin but still take up over 1TB of space (more then I would like to sit filled but not used).I got some pushback for the application owner from simply deleting the disks I identified as unmounted. Apparently it is a lot of work to recover when existing data is missing.

QUESTION/s:

Is there a way to disconnect the vmdk files to prove the disks are not used? The idea being that if I am wrong,and a disk was needed, I would get a error (linux or vmware error) and I could reconnect the disk.

Alternately is it possible to see if data is being written to a vmdk file? As all disks are re-thinned and I wrote data to them I should see them grow, but is this the most effective way to confirm the disks aren't used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just remove the disk:

[image]

As long as you don't check *Delete files from datastore* the files will stay there and you can add them again:

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Is reattaching just as simple? I guess this is where the "use an existing disk" option would be used when adding a new disk.

Comment: Exactly. Just select the disk file.